# Gap at top of full height viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full-height and full-width html page using `100vh` and `100vw`. I'd like there to be a 2em margin around the content area and 2em of padding inside the edge of the content area.

This seems like a simple thing to accomplish, but for some reason the `<body>` position is shifted 2em from the top of the viewport even though `<html>` and `<body>` have no margin or padding and are set to full width and height.

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="app">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>Why is the body not at the top of the viewport?</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#content {
  background-color: #999;  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.app {
  background-color: white;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
  width: calc(100vw - 4em);
  margin: 2em;
}
```

Notice that the content area scrolls. There should be no scrolling. Here is a live example:
http://codepen.io/tauren/pen/MpeBdx

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.app`

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#content {
  background-color: #999;  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.app {
  background-color: white;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
  width: calc(100vw - 4em);
  margin: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: No need to add another rule, just delete the 2em top-margin on .app

Comment: No, this won't help. You can try to delete margin in his pen, and you'll see that gap remain and scrollbars don't disappear.

Comment: So this does fix it, but I'm wanting to understand why the `.app` margin is affecting the `body` location. Also, the `app` needs to be `display: flex`, I should have put that into the codepen.

Comment: This is caused by collapsing margins. You can find out more here: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

Comment: If your .app needs to be flex, add display: inline-block; to #content

Comment: This answers the question as well as solves it. @LGSon gave essentially the same answer, but Guardian commented about collapsing margins 8 seconds before that post, so I'm selecting this answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tauren Of course you pick which ever, though a good answer should have an explanation within the answer, not as a comment, as they might be deleted ... 8 seconds or not :) ... and if you really is going to count seconds, I started to write my post long time before that comment were posted :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because *collapsing margins*, which you can read up on here [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

In your case, and simply put, the margin you gave the `.app` adds to the height given to the `#content`, hence scroll occurs.

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `#content` class is one way to solve that

```
#content {
  background-color: #999;  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpEVyz)

Answer (score 0):

.app has a 2em margin:

```
.app {
 background-color: white;
 height: calc(100vh - 4em);
 margin: 2em;
 width: calc(100vw - 4em);
}
```

UPDATE:

Remove the margin from .app and simply add 2em padding to the #content

Comment: Yes it does, that's the objective. In the codepen, you can see the grey border around the left, right, and bottom. But it is white at the top. The `<body>` actually starts 2em down. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`.app` and `h3` have margins too

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#content {
  background-color: #999;  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.app {
  background-color: white;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
  width: calc(100vw - 4em);
  margin: 0 2em 2em 2em;
}

h3{
  margin-top : 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the do have margins. But I'm trying to understand why they would cause the body to start lower. They should be contained inside the body, not affect the body.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin from .app and add 2em padding to #content

Comment: content area still scrolls with this solution. it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 border-top: 1px solid gold !important;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
```

to your content. Working [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMJxeW)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

}

#content {
  background-color: #999;  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
   border-top: 1px solid gold !important; /*MODIFICATION*/
  margin-top: -1px !important; /*MODIFICATION */
}

.app {
  background-color: white;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
  width: calc(100vw - 4em);
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="app">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>Why is the body not at the top of the viewport?</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not a fan of using `!important`